# Processing localised date to convert it to local date/time using moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am getting translated UTC date from the backend and need to convert the date to localised local time format before displaying on the screen.

I have been using,

```
moment.locale(currentLocale); //Here currentLocale is the user's locale.
localtime = moment.utc(inputDate).toDate(); // inputDate = 2017年11月01日  AM10:42 (GMT)
moment(localtime).format(formatType); //formatType = "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm A"
```

This works fine when the date is in english but not when we get translated date.

Is there any way we can process translated date to convert it to locale date and time and if possible translate digits too.

Comment: You should always provide the format of the date when parsing, otherwise you're just letting the parser guess. See [*moment(string, string)*](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Answer (score 0):

You should give the parser the format of the string you're parsing. You must be ignoring the error you're getting.

```js
var inputDate = 'inputDate = 2017年11月01日  AM10:42 (GMT)'
var parseFormat = 'YYYY MM DD  Ah:mm';
var printFormat = 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm A';

var d = moment.utc(inputDate, parseFormat).toDate();
console.log('Local: ' + moment(d).format(printFormat));
console.log('UTC  : ' + moment.utc(d).format(printFormat));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The technique of parsing a string to a moment object, then creating an ECMAScript Date just to parse it back into a moment.utc object is weird to me. There doesn't seem to be a way of parsing a string as UTC without then setting the output offset to UTC too.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This helped a lot. The problem with me is that I am not aware of the format the date will come from the backend and therefore, cannot use a fixed 'parseFormat'. I am trying to get a format from backend to process the date as required. Let me know if there is any way around to this.