# How to convert localized date string to date object using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using moment how can we convert localized date string to javascript date object?
Followed below steps, but got Current Output(check below).

How can we get Expected Output?

Could you please help me.

Ex: Setting moment locale as `'fr'`

```
moment.defineLocale('fr', [localeObject][1]);
```

Now we get the date string as **"27 févr. 2020 18:23:50"**

How can we convert it as dateobject?

```
moment("27 févr. 2020 18:23:50")
```

**Expected output:**

> Thu Feb 27 2020 18:23:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

**Current Output:**

> Invalid Date

Comment: See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069375/processing-localised-date-to-convert-it-to-local-date-time-using-moment-js

Comment: Thanks for the response.
If we have 12 hours format then the meridian will also be localized. In this case above thread will work or do we need to follow any other way?
seems to be the thread is not working for meridian. Could you please guide me

Comment: It will work, the meridian is just part of the format.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting *Invalid Date* because `"27 févr. 2020 18:23:50"` is not in ISO 8601 nor in RFC 2822 compliant form, so you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). Moreover you have to use french locale, see [i18n](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) section of the doc.

As described in the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), you can use `DD` for days of the month, `MMM` for month name (locale aware), `YYYY` for 4 digit year, `HH` for 0-23 hours (lowercase `hh` for 1-12 hours), `mm` for minutes and `ss` for seconds.

Then you can use [`toDate()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) to get a JavaScript date from a moment object:

> To get a copy of the native Date object that Moment.js wraps, use `moment#toDate`.

Snippet with working code sample:

```js
console.log( moment("27 févr. 2020 18:23:50", "DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss").toDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/fr.js"></script>
```